# ASP.NET MVC - Accessing C# string in client-side JS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my controller method I have the following simple comma separated string that I pass to my view using TempData:

```
var test = "hi,bye";
TempData["test"] = test;
```

In my view, I have the following js method:

```
var desks = @(TempData["test"]).split(",");
```

When I inspect the DOM using the Google Chrome developer console, I see the following:

```
var desks = hi,bye.split(",");
```

Why is the TempData string I pass losing it's quotes and becoming some sort of other object? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you pass does not "lose" its quotes; the string **value** has no quotes, even though the string **literal** does.

You have to perform JavaScript string escaping yourself, something like this:

```
'@(TempData["test"].
    Replace("\\", "\\\\").
    Replace("\n", "\\n").
    Replace("\r", "\\r").
    Replace("'", "\\'"))'.split(",");
```

This will create an escaped string that is probably safe enough to output as a JavaScript string literal.

Another alternative is to call on JSON serialization to output the string, which will cover all your bases.

```
@Html.Raw((new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(TempData["test"])) .split(",");
```

`JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize` will take any object *(in this case, a string)* and output it in a way that JavaScript understands.

`Html.Raw` will then make sure that the output from `Serialize` is written to the output stream **without HTML-encoding**.

The extra space between the last `)` of C# code and the JavaScript `.split` is necessary. Without it, `split` is interpreted by Razor as the name of a C# method, which it is not.

To use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class, just add a `@using System.Web.Script.Serialization` directive at the top of your view.

Comment: `@((new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(TempData["test"])).split(",");` outputs: `&quot;hi,bye&quot;.split(",")`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Thanks but I think there's still a typo in there. Should be: `@Html.Raw((new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(TempData["test"]).Split(','));`

Comment: If you follow my advice to add a `@using` directive, you won't have to include all that.

Comment: I know. That's not where the typo was. There were one too many brackets in the wrong place and the Split required single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: No, the `split` function is a JavaScript method of the `String` object, it is **lowercase** and can take a string as a parameter, which can have both single and double quotes. Make sure you add a space between the last `)` and `.split`. Otherwise, Razor will think that `.split` is a C# method.

Comment: Yes, but .split() is being highlighted in red because there is some syntax error in your code.

Comment: No, there is no syntax error. Make sure you add a space between the last `)` and `.split`. Otherwise, Razor will think that .split is a C# method, which it is not.

Comment: Sorry Anders, didn't realize the space was important. It's working now. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it:

```
'@(TempData["test"])'.split(",");
```

Javascript won't interpret if it's a string in C# or not. It just write the string in the code. You need to manually input the quotes before and after the C# code, so javascript will read the `hi,bye` as string.

Comment: That won't work if the string value contains any of the following characters: ', \, linefeed characters.

Comment: Knowing that I will never have those characters in my specific context, this solution does work. But do note Anders' comment, this is not a 100% solution.